# Show $\lim_{a \to 0} a \cdot \mu (\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : |f(x)| > a \}) = 0$ for $f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$, $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$, and $a > 0$. Show
>
> $$
> \lim_{a \to 0} a \cdot \mu (E_a) = 0
> $$
>
> where $E_a = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : |f(x)| > a \}$.

---

**Try**

Since

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |f| d\mu = \int_{E_a} |f| d\mu + \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E_a } |f| d\mu < \infty
$$

we have $\int_{E_a} |f| d\mu < \infty$, $\forall a$.

But I'm stuck at how I can relate this to find $\mu(E_a)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a consequence of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Note that
$$
a\cdot 1_{\{|f(x)|>a\}}\leq |f(x)|
$$ for all $a>0$. Thus for any sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \downarrow 0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \cdot\mu(E_{a_n}) =\int \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n\cdot 1_{\{|f(x)|>a_n\}}\right)d\mu =\int 0d\mu = 0.
$$ This establishes $$\lim_{a\to 0} a\cdot\mu(E_a) =0.$$

Note: One can see that $a\cdot \mu(E_a)$ is the area of a rectangle below the graph $\{(x,|f(x)|) \;|\;x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ of $|f|$ which has finite area by the assumption. This observation is the motivation of this approach.

Comment: Can you explain the connection between the note and the solution? (I know what both say, I just don't see the connection)

Comment: In fact, it's just heuristics. Consider, for example, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and a curve $(t,f(t)),t\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $a\cdot\mu(|f|>a)= 2a\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{a}}=2\sqrt{a(1-a)}$ is the area of the largest rectangle with height $a$ below the curve, and we can see that as $a\to 0$, this area converges to $0$. We can generalize this to general $f\in L^1$.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with dominated convergence theorem. your comment just gave an explanation of why the result is true, but it did not shed light on how it was the motivation of your approach, i.e. how it motivated you to use DCT

Comment: Yes, you're right. Intuition itself does not tell we should use DCT. I selected DCT as an appropriate tool to rigorously prove my intuition. But it somehow tells us that we need some kind of integral limit theorem.

Comment: lol just because you used it doesn't tell us that we need some form of it. Problem 15 on page 321 of Carothers real analysis book says that if $f$ is non-negative and in $L^1$, then $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} 2^k\mu(\{f > 2^k\}) < \infty$. This kind of result (which is very easy to prove) will also give a proof

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so I guess I used the term 'need' inappropriately. I'm not saying  that it is the only way to prove this result. There are possibly so many valid approaches. What I mean is that when I had the intuition in my head, what comes to my mind next is that DCT would be able to show it.

Comment: I think you are lying. Specifically, I think this is a lie:

"What I mean is that when I had the intuition in my head, what comes to my mind next is that DCT would be able to show it."

You said 

"I selected DCT as an appropriate tool to rigorously prove my intuition."

and then you said 

"But it somehow tells us that we need some kind of integral limit theorem." So you're clearly saying more than the fact that DCT was the next thing to pop into your mind. You said that you need to use something like DCT. Don't blame this on English.

Comment: In any event, I did give your solution a +1

Comment: Now, I don't get the point of you arguing that I'm lying. Maybe in the first place, my note at the end of my answer was inappropriate? I'm just saying that when one is lost and don't know where to go, one can be guided by seeing what is happening on the area of the rectangle below the graph of $|f|$. This is of course just one 'suggestion' and I suggest it to explain my argument more visually rather than just algebraically.

Comment: If I'm mistaken and you are upset about it, then I feel sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not upset. I just (rationally) think you were lying. I suggest you reread the comment explaining it. These last two comments you just made seem completely irrelevant to what I was talking about.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. And what I said in the comments were not very consistent... So forget about it and go back to your original question. Would you explain what exactly you want from your very first comment? I think I don't really get it.

Comment: I just wanted to know how that area interpretation led to the use of DCT. But, as you said, there is probably no intuitive explanation.

Comment: To make clear, area interpretation does not necessarily lead to the use of LDCT. I mean there is no explicit logical connection. (And I didn't intend to argue that there is one.) It is just about interpreting the expression $a\cdot\mu(E_a)$ somewhat geometrically as a first step to see that the result is very probable. Not to lose mathematical rigor, one should justifty taking limit $a\to 0$, and coming up with the LDCT to this end is another step, it's up to one who is solving it. (though if one is familiar with the application of LDCT, it almost comes immediately.) I hope I made it clear.